# R function to plot inequalities with shading

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, inequality

Suppose I have a set of inequalities:

```
  -2x + y <= -3
1.25x + y <= 2.5
        y >= -3
```

And I can summarize the information as follows:

```
mat <- matrix(c(-2, 1, 1.25, 1, 0, 1), nrow = 3, byrow = TRUE)
dir <- c("<=", "<=", ">=")
rhs <- c(-3, 2.5, -3)
```

I wrote the following function to plot the inequalities:

```
plot(0, 0, xlim = c(-1, 5), ylim = c(-4, 1))
plot_ineq <- function(mat, dir, rhs, xlow, xhigh){
  line <- list()
  for(i in 1:nrow(mat)){
    if(mat[i, 2] > 0){
      line[[i]] <- sapply(seq(xlow, xhigh, 0.1), function(x) (rhs[i] - mat[i, 1] * x)/mat[i, 2])
    }else if(mat[i, 2] < 0){
      line[[i]] <- sapply(seq(xlow, xhigh, 0.1), function(x) (rhs[i] - mat[i, 1] * x)/mat[i, 2])
      if(dir[i] == ">="){
        dir[i] = "<="
      }else dir[i] = ">="
    }
    lines(seq(xlow, xhigh, 0.1), line[[i]])
  }
}

plot_ineq(mat = mat, dir = dir, rhs = rhs, xlow = -1, xhigh = 5)
```

[image]

I have two questions: (1) how can I have a blank plot without having the `(0, 0)` point there? and (2) how can I shade the corresponding region according to `dir`? Should I try ggplot2?

I'm simply looking to shade the area that is described by the set of inequalities above. Not where `(0, 0)` lies.

Comment: (1) `plot(0, 0, type = "n", etc)`

Comment: OR  `plot(NULL, xlim = c(-1, 5), ylim = c(-4, 1))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**1)** Change the last inequality to be the same direction as the others and then use plotPolytope in gMOIP.

```
library(gMOIP)
mat <- matrix(c(-2, 1, 1.25, 1, 0, -1), nrow = 3, byrow = TRUE)
rhs <- c(-3, 2.5, 3)

argsFaces <- list(argsGeom_polygon = list(fill = "blue"))
plotPolytope(mat, rhs, argsFaces = argsFaces)
```

giving (continued after image)

[image: screenshot]

**2)** The above uses ggplot2 graphics but if you prefer classic graphics then using mat and rhs from above:

```
library(gMOIP)

cp <- cornerPoints(mat, rhs)
cp <- cp[chull(cp), ]  # chull gives indices of convex hull in order
plot(cp, type = "n")
polygon(cp, col = "blue")

# not shown but to add lines run this too
for(i in 1:nrow(cp)) {
  ix <- if (i < nrow(cp)) i + 0:1 else c(i, 1)
  b <- diff(cp[ix, 2]) / (d <- diff(cp[ix, 1]))
  if (abs(d) < 1e-5) abline(v = a <- cp[i, 1])
  else abline(a = a <- cp[i, 2] - b * cp[i, 1], b = b)
}
```

giving (continued after image)

[image: screenshot]

**3)** Note that there is an archived package named [intpoint](https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/intpoint/) on CRAN and it could be used to draw the boundary of the feasible region and lines. It does have the limitation that it is hard coded to show X and Y axes between -1 and 5 although it might not be hard to generalize it. It is used like this (output not shown) where mat, rhs and cp are from above.

```
library(intpoint)

intpoint:::show2d(mat, rhs, c = numeric(2))
polygon(cp, col = "blue")
```